# Verification of the sound heard for the last vowel of "Virginia" in the Rolling Stones song "You Can't Always Get What You Want"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, vowels

In this [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv9sDn_2XkI), at 3 min  18 s is found the name "Virginia" and my ear tells me that, for some reason or other, the a of this name is pronounced /e/ and not /ə/; shortly after that, in the word "sorbet" the e is pronounced /ə/, as it should, and I have no problem hearing it. Could someone who trust their ears deny or confirm this fact?

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: Why do you think that somebody wouldn't pronounce the same thing differently? (I myself am not often consistent in the way I pronounce things, changing how I say them from one context to the next.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: The lyrics are not *Virginia*, but "I was standing in line with Mr. Jimmy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lyrics](https://genius.com/The-rolling-stones-you-cant-always-get-what-you-want-lyrics) say the word you're hearing is not *Virginia*, it's *terjimmy* (the last three syllables of *Mister Jimmy*, not *Miss Virginia*). So the phoneme should be /i/ or /ɪ/. (Which is closer to /e/ than /ə/ is.)

Comment: I was so sure of hearing "Virginia" it never occurred to me to check the lyrics.

Comment: When I listened to it after reading your question, I heard *Miss Virginia*, too. But it didn't quite sound right, so I decided to check the lyrics.